# Data servlet to JSP without changing URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the JSP page which calls servlet . In servlet, data is fetched from DB and sent to JSP using request.dispatcher. Everything works fine but initial page URL looks like http://localhost:8080/Sample/employee.jsp and after calling servlet changes URL to http://localhost:8080/Sample/getEmployeeDetails .. I want same URL ie, http://localhost:8080/Sample/employee.jsp even after calling servlet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: *I have the JSP page which calls servlet*. I cannot guess what you means. A JSP page (which is indeed compiled into a servlet) can *include*, *forward to* or *redirect to* another servlet. It can even contains a forms that submits input data to the other servlet. Please give details and ideally simplified code. This question is currently unclear...

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to provide REST API (json) and call it through AJAX (from JavaScript). Upon success, just change the value of the `data_field` to whatever you received.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'url/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json;",
    success: [function (data) {
        document.getElementById("data_field").value = data.value;
    }]
});
```

Depending on what type of field you're using for data (div, span, etc) you might have to change `x.value` to something else, like `x.innerHTML`, to make it work for your case.

Comment: Can't we achieve without ajax request?

Comment: @Ramesh I don't know of any other way, sorry. I believe that's how most applications do it

Comment: @Ramesh `iframe` is another way for you